# Geração de Guias GNRE para o estado de RJ

Tags: delphi, web-service, soap

Bom dia,

Eu estou realizando o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação que realizado a geração e o envio de guias GNRE para o estado do Rio de Janeiro. Eu ja fiz o desenvolvimento para o ambiente nacional e está funcionando, porém o estado do RJ não é integrado com o ambiente nacional.

Eu estou seguindo a documentação disponível no site do estado.
http://www.fazenda.rj.gov.br/sefaz/faces/oracle/webcenter/portalapp/pages/navigation-renderer.jspx?_afrLoop=167210291667000&datasource=UCMServer%23dDocName%3A3380027&_adf.ctrl-state=nymmlq023_36

Eu estou fazendo a utilização para comunicação com o webservice o componente TIdHttp e estou tendo o seguinte problema.

[image: 500 Internal Server Error]

Eu estou realizando o envio do seguinte XML ao servidor:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <enviarDados>
        <emitente>
            <CnpjEmitente>33042730001771</CnpjEmitente>
            <Email>dfsdf@csn.com.br</Email>
        </emitente>
        <documentos>
            <Documento>
                <DataPagamento>29/05/2013</DataPagamento>
                <ItensPagamentos>
                    <ItemPagamento>
                        <CepContribuinte>27260390</CepContribuinte>
                        <Cnpj>33042730001771</Cnpj>
                        <CodigoProduto>000000000477</CodigoProduto>
                        <DataVencimento>23/05/2013</DataVencimento>
                        <DddContribuinte>243</DddContribuinte>
                        <DiaVencimento>23</DiaVencimento>
                        <EnderecoContribuinte>RODOVIA BR 393 - LUCIO S/N, KM 5001 VILA SANTA CECILIA</EnderecoContribuinte>
                        <InformacoesComplementares>ADFASDF</InformacoesComplementares>
                        <InscEstadualRJ>80541767</InscEstadualRJ>
                        <MunicipioContribuinte>VOLTA REDONDA</MunicipioContribuinte>
                        <Natureza>000000000004</Natureza>
                        <NomeRazaoSocial>COMPANHIA SIDERURGICA NACIONAL - CS</NomeRazaoSocial>
                        <NotaFiscalCnpj>46044053004607</NotaFiscalCnpj>
                        <NotaFiscalDataEmissao>23/05/2013</NotaFiscalDataEmissao>
                        <NotaFiscalNumero>000000002</NotaFiscalNumero>
                        <NotaFiscalSerie>1</NotaFiscalSerie>
                        <NotaFiscalTipo>NF-e</NotaFiscalTipo>
                        <NumControleContribuinte>0000032669</NumControleContribuinte>
                        <TelefoneContribuinte>2433445194</TelefoneContribuinte>
                        <TipoApuracao>2</TipoApuracao>
                        <TipoId>1</TipoId>
                        <UfContribuinte>RJ</UfContribuinte>
                        <ValorFECPPrincipal>0.02</ValorFECPPrincipal>
                        <ValorICMSPrincipal>0.12</ValorICMSPrincipal>
                        <ValorTotal>0.14</ValorTotal>
                    </ItemPagamento>
                </ItensPagamentos>
                <SqDocumento>1</SqDocumento>
                <TipoDocumento>1</TipoDocumento>
                <TipoPagamento>1</TipoPagamento>
            </Documento>
        </documentos>
    </enviarDados>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

O fonte que realiza o envio das requisições ao webservice:

```
function TWebServiceSOAP.Execute(XML: String): String;
var
  Retorno, Envio: TStringStream;
begin
 try
    Envio := TStringStream.Create(XML);
    Retorno := TStringStream.Create(EmptyStr);
    IdHttp.getCustomHeaders.Add(Format('SOAPAction: "%s"', [SOAPAction]));
    try
      IdHttp.post(Envio, Retorno);
    except On E:Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end; 
    Result := Retorno.DataString;
 finally
    if Assigned(Envio) then
       FreeAndNil(Envio);
    if Assigned(Retorno) then
       FreeAndNil(Retorno);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui descobrir oque ocorria. O problema era o XML.

Segue o XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://www.openuri.org/">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
    <enviarDados>
        <emitente>
            <CnpjEmitente>33042730001771</CnpjEmitente>
            <Email>dfsdf@csn.com.br</Email>
        </emitente>
        <documentos>
            <Documento>
                <DataPagamento>29/05/2013</DataPagamento>
                <ItensPagamentos>
                    <ItemPagamento>
                        <CepContribuinte>27260390</CepContribuinte>
                        <Cnpj>33042730001771</Cnpj>
                        <CodigoProduto>000000000477</CodigoProduto>
                        <DataVencimento>23/05/2013</DataVencimento>
                        <DddContribuinte>243</DddContribuinte>
                        <DiaVencimento>23</DiaVencimento>
                        <EnderecoContribuinte>RODOVIA BR 393 - LUCIO S/N, KM 5001 VILA SANTA CECILIA</EnderecoContribuinte>
                        <InformacoesComplementares>ADFASDF</InformacoesComplementares>
                        <InscEstadualRJ>80541767</InscEstadualRJ>
                        <MunicipioContribuinte>VOLTA REDONDA</MunicipioContribuinte>
                        <Natureza>000000000004</Natureza>
                        <NomeRazaoSocial>COMPANHIA SIDERURGICA NACIONAL - CS</NomeRazaoSocial>
                        <NotaFiscalCnpj>46044053004607</NotaFiscalCnpj>
                        <NotaFiscalDataEmissao>23/05/2013</NotaFiscalDataEmissao>
                        <NotaFiscalNumero>000000002</NotaFiscalNumero>
                        <NotaFiscalSerie>1</NotaFiscalSerie>
                        <NotaFiscalTipo>NF-e</NotaFiscalTipo>
                        <NumControleContribuinte>0000032669</NumControleContribuinte>
                        <TelefoneContribuinte>2433445194</TelefoneContribuinte>
                        <TipoApuracao>2</TipoApuracao>
                        <TipoId>1</TipoId>
                        <UfContribuinte>RJ</UfContribuinte>
                        <ValorFECPPrincipal>0.02</ValorFECPPrincipal>
                        <ValorICMSPrincipal>0.12</ValorICMSPrincipal>
                        <ValorTotal>0.14</ValorTotal>
                    </ItemPagamento>
                </ItensPagamentos>
                <SqDocumento>1</SqDocumento>
                <TipoDocumento>1</TipoDocumento>
                <TipoPagamento>1</TipoPagamento>
            </Documento>
        </documentos>
    </enviarDados>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```